# How can I add psychic damage to wizard powers?

Tags: dnd-4e, wizard, implements, keywords

If I want to add the psychic keyword to my wizard powers, the only thing I can come up with is to get heavy blades as an implement, and use a Githyanki Silver Sword. Are there any other ways to get it? In particular, a way that will allow me to take a superior implement?

Answer (score 2):

The only other weapons that convert damage to psychic is the Mindiron Weapon (bow/crossbow only), and Sorrowsong Blade (Heavy Blade only). These come with an always on 1/2 damage psychic property. There are no implements that change the damage to psychic.

The better choice would be to take a healthy slate of psychic keyword powers. Wizards usually have a psychic choice or two at every level.

Comment: You could also toss in some Arcane Admixture selections on some choice powers, but if I recall (it's been a while since I played 4e), that's a Paragon level feat.

Comment: @Ellesedil tbh that's when you should actually start caring about damage types anyways. Most damage type feats start then.

Comment: Arcane Admixture does not give you Psychic.

Comment: @András good point, that is *not* an option for psychic.

Answer (score 1):

Talk to the DM and see if you can re-flavor your powers to be psychic.

There was an article on doing exactly that in Dungeon #394 Dec 2010:

> It is also possible to change the damage type of
>   powers or feats to better fit a character—with the
>   Dungeon Master’s permission. For example, a disproportionate
>   number of feats favor cold-using characters;
>   changing those feats to another damage type should not
>   automatically break the game. Such a change should not
>   be made lightly, without considering the ramifications,
>   and certainly not without consulting the DM.

The article also touches on modifying classes and races, an example given is a minotaur warlock turning its *eldritch blast* into and *eldritch strike*.